# Integrating fraction of exponentials

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to integrate
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty{\frac{e^{t(4\omega-1)}}{1-e^{t2\omega}\kappa}dt}
\end{align}
with $\omega<0$ and $\kappa \in [-1,0]$. I tried substitution, but got stuck.
Here is what I did so far. 
\begin{align}
[1-\kappa,1] \ni s := 1-e^{t2\omega}\kappa \quad &\Longleftrightarrow \quad t = \frac{1}{2\omega}\ln\left(\frac{1-s}{\kappa}\right)\\
\frac{ds}{dt} = -2\omega e^{t2\omega}\kappa \quad &\Longleftrightarrow \quad dt = \frac{ds}{-2\omega \kappa e^{t2\omega}}
\end{align}
 and hence consider
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty{\frac{e^{t(4\omega-1)}}{1-e^{t2\omega}\kappa}dt} & = -\int_{1-\kappa}^1{\frac{e^{t(4\omega-1)}}{2s\omega \kappa e^{t2\omega}}ds}\\[4mm]
& = -\int_{1-\kappa}^1{\frac{e^{t(2\omega-1)}}{2s\omega \kappa}ds}\\[4mm]
& = -\int_{1-\kappa}^1{\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2\omega}\ln\left(\frac{1-s}{\kappa}\right)(2\omega-1)}}{2s\omega \kappa}ds}\\[4mm]
& = -\int_{1-\kappa}^1{\frac{\left(\frac{1-s}{\kappa}\right)^\frac{2\omega-1}{2\omega}}{2s\omega \kappa}ds}\\[4mm]
& = -\int_{1-\kappa}^1{\frac{(1-s)^\frac{2\omega-1}{2\omega}}{2s\omega\kappa^\frac{4\omega-1}{2\omega}}ds}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral does not seem to be elementary.  By taking a series in powers of $\kappa$ I get (at least for  $|\kappa|<1$, though I think it works for all $\omega,\kappa < 0$ by analytic continuation)

$$\frac{- \Phi \left( 
\kappa,1,{\frac {4\,\omega-1}{2\omega}} \right) }{2\omega}
$$
where $\Phi$ is the Lerch Phi function.

EDIT: Lerch Phi has the [integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Integral_representations)

$$ \Phi(\kappa, 1,a) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-as}}{1-\kappa e^{-s}}\; ds$$
where $\text{Re}(a) > 0$ and $\kappa < 1$.  Here we want $a = (4\omega - 1)/(2\omega) = 2 - 1/(2\omega)$; note that $\omega < 0$ implies $a > 2$.
Change variables to $t = -s/(2\omega)$ and (with $\omega < 0$) this becomes
$-2 \omega$ times your integral.

Comment: Thanks. I added the bounds for $\kappa$.

Comment: Would you mind showing how to derive it? If $-\Phi(\kappa,1,\frac{4\omega - 1}{2\omega})/2\omega = -\int_0^\infty{\frac{e^{-t\frac{4\omega - 1}{2\omega}}}{1-\kappa e^{-t}}dt}/2\omega$ I would't know how my original integrand coincides.